# Android app and webpage with the same Ruby on rails backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to do a Ruby on rails webpage that can be seen in an android app with react native.
I know I can use the --api flag, but would it be a problem if I also want to access the website in a web navigator? or could I create the android front if I don't use the --api flag?
I want them both to have different frontend

I'm new with RoR so currently I'm just investigating my options

Comment: You could definitely create Rails application as API. And after that create react native app AND regular frontend application (via react or vue). I have done it, worked perfectly. You even could create default rails application with frontend and backend as usual and also add api controllers to use from android app